# Accessing colors in a resource dictionary from a value converter

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I defined several colors in a ResourceDictionary. e.g.:

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
  <Color x:Key=Gray1>#FFF7F1F3</Color>
  <Color x:Key=Gray2>#FFDDD8DA</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So I can reuse them everywhere in application.

Now I wrote a value converter to convert the items inner state to the related color.

How can I access the defined colors in the code of the value converter?

My first thought was to pass the dictionary as converter parameter. But I don't know how to achieve that.

Regards

**EDIT**

`Application.Current.Resources` is not an option. Because I won't have access to it later.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The annoying thing about using a converter parameter is that you have to add that text every single time you want to use the binding.

Instead you could make the ResourceDictionary a property on your converter and set it when you instantiate the converter.

code for converter:

```
public class SomeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private ResourceDictionary _resourceDictionary;
    public ResourceDictionary ResourceDictionary
    {
        get { return _resourceDictionary; }
        set 
        {
            _resourceDictionary = value; 
        }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //do your own thing using the _dict
        //var person = value as Person
        //if (person.Status == "Awesome")
        //    return _resourceDictionary["AwesomeBrush"]
        //else
        //    return _resourceDictionary["NotAwesomeBrush"];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

instantiate and use converter:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SomeConverter x:Key="MyConverter" >
        <local:SomeConverter.ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="SomeRandomResourceDictionary.xaml" />
        </local:SomeConverter.ResourceDictionary>
    </local:SomeConverter>
</Window.Resources>

...

<StackPanel Background="{Binding CurrentPerson, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" >
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Nice one. That saves my day. Thanks.

Comment: Just came across this - I'm trying to achieve this too. Does this solution not create a new instance of every item in the ResourceDictionary? Or is WPF smart enough to recognise that it has already been loaded, and to use only the one set of values?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 & 2017 throws an error in design-mode: 
Unable to cast object of type 'OnDemandResourceDictionary' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.DocumentModel.DocumentCompositeNode'. How to beat it?

Comment: @yatskovsky I don't have a ton of time to dig/test various solutions, but perhaps messing with design time resources would at least prevent it from crashing?Google this: "xaml design time resources"

Comment: @viggity Thank you for the idea.