# Bind Image source to string

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am using a column in my table which displays an image:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fill" Width="1*" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding fill}" Width="15px" Height="15px"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C#:

```
// CustomRow contains a public member called fill
public List<CustomRow> tableList;
//...
this.table.ItemsSource = this.tableList;
```

I decided it would be better to use resources. So my plan is to bind the image source to a resource. I have created a test resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="test-icon" UriSource="Resources/testicon.png" />
</Window.Resources>
```

I want to bind `fill` to the image source, so when `fill = "test-icon"` it displays the image as resource. How can I do that?

Comment: You mean like `<Image Source="{StaticResource test-icon}"`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes exactly. I tried `Source="{StaticResource {Binding fill}}"` but that doesn't work.

Comment: But... what's `fill`? A property of your viewmodel? What's in it?

Comment: In my code I have a `List<CustomRow>`. CustomRow is a class which contains a member called `fill`. The list is then set as the grids ItemsSource.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have added it to my question.

Comment: You know what, it sounds like you're successfully displaying an image already. What's the goal here? P.S. If somebody asks you what `fill` is, the answer to that question isn't "Some other property of some other class is a List of something I refuse to describe".

Comment: @EdPlunkett It's a string. Currently fill contains `"pack://application:,,,/Resources/testicon.png". As far as I understood that means the image gets loaded into memory again for every single row. I am displaying thousands of rows. That's why I wanted to use it as a reusable resource.

Comment: The list simply holds the content of the table. `CustomRow` has a member for every column.

Comment: If they're all the same image, then one resource would do it and my first comment is your answer. But WPF won't be creating thousands of Image controls in any case. Just the visible ones. When a grid row scrolls out of view, that actual row control will be recycled with a new DataContext for the next row that scrolls into view. If only 30 rows are ever visible, that's all the controls it'll ever create. This is called "Virtualization".

Comment: Okay. But there are three different different images which can be shown in that column. That's why a simple resource is not working here. I noticed "lags" in the table on low performant computers.

Comment: I would first test the assumption that the images are the cause of the lag, by replacing the image thing with one single hard-coded image (or removing the image entirely, better yet!), and running that version of the application on the slowest computer I could find. The critical thing in optimization is first identifying, with certainty, the cause of the problem, before spending any time or effort on a solution to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing colors in a resource dictionary from a value converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238590/accessing-colors-in-a-resource-dictionary-from-a-value-converter). Not specifically for images, but it works the exact same way.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a converter that looks up the resource based on the value of the source property:

```
public class ResourceConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentWindowProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("ParentWindow", typeof(Window), typeof(ResourceConverter));

    public Window ParentWindow
    {
        get { return (Window)GetValue(ParentWindowProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ParentWindowProperty, value); }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string resourceKey = value as string;
        if (ParentWindow == null || resourceKey == null)
            return value;

        return ParentWindow.Resources[resourceKey];

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

---

```
<Window ... x:Name="win>
    <Window.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="test-icon" UriSource="Resources/testicon.png" />
    </Window.Resources>
...
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:ResourceConverter x:Key="ResourceConverter"
                                 ParentWindow="{Binding Source={x:Reference win}}" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fill" Width="1*" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=fill, Converter={StaticResource ResourceConverter}}"
                                   Width="15px" Height="15px"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```